# Error ModuleNotFound incluso con ficheros init

Tags: python

A ver si alguien me ilumina. Estoy teniendo problemas en importar clases desde la carpeta src/ de mi proyecto a otra carpeta llamada tests/. Dentro de cada una existe un fichero llamado init.py que tiene la intencion de convertir estas carpetas en modulos, pero no consigo lo que quiero.

Llamando a clases de gilded_rose.py desde el fichero test_normal_item.py:

from src.gilded_rose import Normal_Item, Stock_Item, Gilded_Rose

Recibo

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

La estructura del proyecto es

```
guilded_rose
├── src
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── gilded_rose.py
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test_normal_item.py
```

NO estoy utilizando ningun tipo de libreria para los casos test y mi editor es VSCode.

Comment: `from ..src.gilder_rose import Normal_Item` quizás? (creo que necesitaría otro `__init__.py` en la carpeta `guilded_rose`)

Comment: Probablemente la ruta de tu proyecto no se halle en el `sys.path`, prueba a incluirla así: `sys.path.append('ruta')`

Comment: Agrega el codigo de como estas importando los modulos.

Answer (score 0):

El error es porque tu modulo **src** no aparece en la lista de directorios donde el interprete de Python busca los modulos (**sys.path**)

Podrías añadir la ruta de tus modulos de esta manera:

```py
import sys, os

carpeta_raiz = os.getcwd() # guilded_rose
sys.path.append(carpeta_raiz)

from src.gilded_rose import Normal_Item, Stock_Item, Gilded_Rose
```